# ERD Postgresql relationship between tables

Tags: postgresql

Please forgive me in my question its my firs time to use postgresql. Whenever I generate ERD in Postgresql I couldn't see the [line] that represent the relationship links between tables.

I am expecting to see tables and relationship links between tables.